# Exercise with automorphisms of rational functions field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $E $ be the field of rational functions over $\mathbb Q $ and consider the six automorphisms $$\alpha_1:f (x)\mapsto f (x), \;\alpha_2:f (x)\mapsto f (1/x)$$ $$\alpha_3:f (x)\mapsto f (1/(1-x)), \; \alpha_4:f (x)\mapsto f (1-x)$$ $$\alpha_5 : f (x)\mapsto f (x/(x-1)),\; \alpha_6:f (x)\mapsto f ((x-1)/x).$$ I have to prove that they form a group of authomorphisms $G $ (hence $|G|=6$), and that, named $F=$Inv $G $, $[E:F]\ge 6$. The first point is quite easy, however it is unclear to me why $[E:F]$ is not equal to $6$: a theorem states that if $E $ is a field and $G $ is a finite group group of authomorphisms of $E $, then $E/$Inv $G $ is a Galois extension (theorem 4.7 of Basic Algebra I). This should imply precisely$[E:F]=|G|$, so I must be wrong somewhere; thanks for any explanation.

Comment: You proved $[E:F]\geq 6$. This does not preclude equality.

Comment: Of course I know, however I think that the professor would write $[E:F]\ge 6$ only if one can't (easily) prove that the strict equality holds.

Comment: Or if it were much more difficult than the rest of the problem, which might very well be the case here.

Comment: Anyway you say that the strict equality holds, do you?

Comment: No; you can prove $[E:F]\geq 6$ even if **equality** holds, but it may be more difficult to show equality than to show the inequality. Showing something is "at least six" is usually easier than showing something is "exactly six". The professors would also ask you to prove $[E:F]\geq 6$ rather than $[E:F]=6$ if the latter is much harder than the former. There is absolutely no reason to think that he would only ask you for the inequality if the "real" answer is strict inequality.

Comment: Yes @André3000, thanks a lot